# How to show objects inside html elements like console?

Tags: javascript, object, console.log

I wanna show the whole object inside a paragraph called "demo", and i want the object to be shown similar to the way that it will be in the console. But instead of that it returns "[object object]" inside the paragraph.
Is there a way to show it like console.log method inside the paragraph?.
Here is my code :

```js
var obj = {
  subobj: {prop1: "value1", prop2: "value2", prop3: "value3"},
};

var var1 = "subobj";

function func() {
  for (x in obj) {
    if (var1 == x) {
      // i want it to be shown like the console.log method
      // console.log(obj[x])
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj[x];
    }
  }
};

func()
```

Comment: try JSON.stringify , although this method will strip away functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just [`stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) the whole object rather than looping through each key/value pair and put the result in a `pre` element:

```
function func(obj) {

  // null refers to an optional replacer function which we won't
  // use in this instance. 2 is an optional parameter to set the 
  // indentation, in this case 2 spaces
  var json = JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = json;
};
```

OUTPUT

```
{
  "subobj": {
    "prop1": "value1",
    "prop2": "value2",
    "prop3": "value3"
  }
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/npxo4cae/3/)

Answer (score 2):

Try and use this:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(obj[x])
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps:

```
var obj = {"objects":[
    {"prop1": "obj1 value1", "prop2": "obj1 value2"},
    {"prop1": "obj 2 value1", "prop2": "obj2 value2"}
]};

function func() {
    var html = "";
    for (var i=0; i < obj.objects.length; i++) {
            // i want it to be shown like the console.log method
            // console.log(obj[x])
        html += "<p>" + obj.objects[i].prop1 + obj.objects[i].prop2  + "</p>";

        }

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = html;
    }
func();
```

You used "obj[x]", but you don't have an array of objects in your obj.
And also this is better because you cache the html in a string and only interact with the DOM once, when you call "document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = html;".

Good luck!

Comment: but when i have an array of object what should i do @mihaifarcas